# Determine if iPhone Safari is in vertical viewport mode with CSS

Tags: iphone, css, mobile-safari

I have been using

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px)
```

to determine if the device used for viewing is an iPhone, however, it seems this rule applies to both the vertical and horizontal viewport modes.

How can I determine if the viewport is indeed vertical (i.e. smaller width viewport)? I have tried

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px)
```

but it doesn't seem to register at all.

Also, all styles located under the `(max-width: 480px)` restriction also gets applied to the vertical mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the orintation media queries:

```
/* Portrait */
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    /* Portrait styles */
}
/* Landscape */
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    /* Landscape styles */
}
```

Comment: After posting the question, I by chance stumbled upon this: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ It seemed to do the trick. My final query looked like this for portrait: `@media only screen and (max-width : 320px)` It seems `only` was the required keyword here.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an option "orientation" with media queries ;)

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/how-to-use-css3-orientation-media-queries/

Answer (score 0):

I know you want to do this with CSS, but CSS really isn't the way to detect the iPhone... you should use JavaScript.

And this will help you detect the orientation in JavaScript:

```
function detectOrientation () {  
if ( orientation == 0 ) {  
 document.className = 'portrait';
}  
else if ( orientation == 90 ) {  
 document.className = 'landscape';  
}  
else if ( orientation == -90 ) {  
 document.className = 'landscape'; 
}  
else if ( orientation == 180 ) {  
 document.className = 'portrait'; 
}
}
```